# How to give a zero of new customer when there is no corresponding resultset

Tags: java, sql, swing

This is a question about how many new customers are created during a month..

In the following query, there are 4 possibilities

1. no vip customers, no normal customers
2. one or several vips, but no normal customers
3. no vips, one or several normal customers
4. vip and normals

In the java testing code snippet below,

- whenever 1 happens, nothing shows
- whenever 2 happens, no new normal customers shows
- whenever 3 happens, only new normal customers shows, no new vips shows
- whenever 4 happens, it doesn't matter

How can I make them appear all the times? Although it is with a count of 0,  I want to do that in the Java code below. Could anyone add some conditions to it, so that this will make that realized?

For example, When the `ResultSet` contains 0 new normal customers, and 5 new VIPs
I want them both to show up in my chart, whenever 5 new normal customers and 0 new VIPs
I want them both to show up too. Currently, whenever there are no order details for one specific type of customer, I mean completely none, that row will be empty

```
select ct.CustomerTypeName AS type, count(DT.CustomerCode) AS cnt , DT.Sales  
  from   
(select ct.CustomerTypeID, ct.CustomerTypeName from customer_type  ct) ct,   
 (select 'VIP' as custType, c.CustomerCode, sum(COALESCE(od.NetSales, 0))  AS Sales   
    from  customer c LEFT JOIN    
      orders o ON (c.CUSTOMERCODE = o.CUSTOMERCODE) LEFT JOIN   
      order_details od ON (od.ORDERCODE = o.ORDERCODE) , VIPLevelUpParam v, ActiveParam a 
      where  
       TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR(c.CustomerCreationDate) AS CHAR(4)) AS VARCHAR(4))) || '-' || 
       TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH(c.CustomerCreationDate)  AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2)))       
         =    
       '2013-11'
        group by  c.CustomerCode, v.LEVELUPAMOUNT, v.LEVELUPID, a.ACTIVEID 
         having  sum(COALESCE(od.NetSales, 0)) >= v.LevelUpAmount   

        union    
      ( select 'Normal' as custType,  c.CustomerCode, sum(COALESCE(od.NetSales, 0)) AS Sales   
         from  customer c LEFT JOIN    
           orders o ON (c.CUSTOMERCODE = o.CUSTOMERCODE) LEFT JOIN   
           order_details od ON (od.ORDERCODE = o.ORDERCODE) , VIPLevelUpParam v, ActiveParam a 
           where  
           TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR(c.CustomerCreationDate) AS CHAR(4)) AS VARCHAR(4))) || '-' ||         TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH(c.CustomerCreationDate)  AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2)))       
            =    
           '2013-11'
           group by c.CustomerCode, v.LEVELUPAMOUNT, v.LEVELUPID, a.ACTIVEID 
           having  sum(COALESCE(od.NetSales, 0)) < v.LevelUpAmount   
           )

 ) DT  
     where ct.CustomerTypeName = custType 
   group by ct.CustomerTypeName, DT.Sales;
```

//////////////////////////

```
for (YearMonth ym : mths)
{
       String sql = getSQL(ym);
       ResultSet rs = getDB().query(sql);

       // condition 1
       if  (!rs.next())
       {

           NewCust nc = new NewCust();
           nc.setType("Normal");
           nc.setYear(ym.getYear());
           nc.setMonth(ym.getMonth());
           nc.setCnt(0);

           NewCustChart cc = new NewCustChart();
           cc.setType(nc.getType());
           cc.setYear(nc.getYear());
           cc.setMonth(nc.getMonth());
           cc.setCnt(0);
           lcc.add(cc);

           nc.setListOfCust(lcc);

           lNewCust.add(nc);

           nc.setType("VIP");
           nc.setYear(ym.getYear());
           nc.setMonth(ym.getMonth());
           nc.setCnt(0);

           cc = new NewCustChart();
           cc.setType(nc.getType());
           cc.setYear(nc.getYear());
           cc.setMonth(nc.getMonth());
           cc.setCnt(0);
           lcc.add(cc);

           nc.setListOfCust(lcc);

           lNewCust.add(nc);


       }
       else
       {
       // condition 2,3,4, but how do I identify which type
         do {
            NewCust nc = new NewCust();
            nc.setType(rs.getString("type"));
            nc.setYear(ym.getYear());
            nc.setMonth(ym.getMonth());


            nc.setCnt(rs.getInt("cnt"));

            NewCustChart cc = new NewCustChart();
            cc.setType(nc.getType());
            cc.setYear(nc.getYear());
            cc.setMonth(nc.getMonth());
            cc.setCnt(nc.getCnt());
            lcc.add(cc);
            nc.setListOfCust(lcc);
            lNewCust.add(nc);
          }while (rs.next());
     }
```

Comment: I think you will need to reformulate your question more clearly.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hard code some data to replace the DB.